# Using Ajax, can I create a function and use it for a click event and on success of an ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Currently I have the following button object with a click event using the usual anonymous function call. This was implemented for previous and next records. The ajax request simply ends up running a mysql query and returning the results, then the page is updated

```js
  ticket_change_buttons.click(function(){
   if(ticket.id.val() != ''){
    options = {
     operation: 'get_relative_ticket',
     ticket_id: ticket.id.val(),
     direction: null
    }
    if($(this).is($('#next_code'))){
     options.direction = 'true';
    }
    if($(this).is($('#prev_code'))){
     options.direction = 'false';
    }
    
    request(options,function(data){
     if(!data){return;}
     ticket.id.val(data.submitid);
    current_id = ticket.id.val();
    ticket.status.val(data.help_status);
    ticket.sub_date.val(data.submit_date);
    ticket.promo_code.val(data.promo_code);
    ticket.fname.val(data.firstname);
    ticket.phone.val(data.phone);
    ticket.zip.val(data.zip_code);
    ticket.acc_num.val(data.account_number);
    ticket.lname.val(data.lastname);
    ticket.email.val(data.email);
    ticket.msg.val(data.message);
    
    /*enable all the inputs*/
    ticket.status.prop('disabled',false);
    ticket.sub_date.removeAttr('disabled');
    ticket.promo_code.removeAttr('disabled');
    ticket.fname.removeAttr('disabled');
    ticket.phone.removeAttr('disabled');
    ticket.zip.removeAttr('disabled');
    ticket.acc_num.removeAttr('disabled');
    ticket.lname.removeAttr('disabled');
    ticket.email.removeAttr('disabled');
    ticket.msg.removeAttr('disabled');
    });
   }
  });
```

There is a second button on the page, which opens the following dialog in order to then make a different ajax request. Here is the code for that dialog:

```js
 notify.resolve_message.window.dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  buttons: {
   "Resolve": function() {
    var options = {
     operation : 'resolve_ticket_only',
     ticket_id : notify.resolve_message.ticket_id.text()
    };
    
    $(this).dialog("close");
    
    request(options, function(data){
     promoTable.table.trigger("update").trigger("sorton", promoTable.table.get(0).config.sortList).trigger("appendCache").trigger("applyWidgets");
     return;
    });
   },
   Cancel: function() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
   }
  },
  width: '440px'
 });
```

How can I (if it is possible) take the anonymous function from ticket_change_buttons.click(function() and make it a function that can be used for both the click and after success of the request in the dialog?

What is already happening on return of the request (the promoTable.table.trigger stuff) still needs to happen. Then the updates from what is currently the click event need to happen.

Comment: Can't you just make a named function with the common functionality in it and then call if from more than one place?  What part of that do you need help with?

Comment: I got it. Don't know why I thought it would be more complex, but this seems to be working:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working. Don't know why I thought it would be more complex

Just made the function and called it in the click event

```js
  ticket_change_buttons.click(prevNext);
  
  function prevNext(){
   if(ticket.id.val() != ''){
    options = {
     operation: 'get_relative_ticket',
     ticket_id: ticket.id.val(),
     direction: null
    }
    // if($(this).is($('#next_code'))){
    //  options.direction = 'true';
    // }
    if($(this).is($('#prev_code'))){
     options.direction = 'false';
    } else {
     options.direction = 'true';
    }
    
    request(options,function(data){
     if(!data){return;}
     ticket.id.val(data.submitid);
    current_id = ticket.id.val();
    ticket.status.val(data.help_status);
    ticket.sub_date.val(data.submit_date);
    ticket.promo_code.val(data.promo_code);
    ticket.fname.val(data.firstname);
    ticket.phone.val(data.phone);
    ticket.zip.val(data.zip_code);
    ticket.acc_num.val(data.account_number);
    ticket.lname.val(data.lastname);
    ticket.email.val(data.email);
    ticket.msg.val(data.message);
    
    /*enable all the inputs*/
    ticket.status.prop('disabled',false);
    ticket.sub_date.removeAttr('disabled');
    ticket.promo_code.removeAttr('disabled');
    ticket.fname.removeAttr('disabled');
    ticket.phone.removeAttr('disabled');
    ticket.zip.removeAttr('disabled');
    ticket.acc_num.removeAttr('disabled');
    ticket.lname.removeAttr('disabled');
    ticket.email.removeAttr('disabled');
    ticket.msg.removeAttr('disabled');
    });
   }
  };
```

and then simply called it after the triggers:

```js
 notify.resolve_message.window.dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  buttons: {
   "Resolve": function() {
    var options = {
     operation : 'resolve_ticket_only',
     ticket_id : notify.resolve_message.ticket_id.text()
    };
    
    $(this).dialog("close");
    
    request(options, function(data){
     promoTable.table.trigger("update").trigger("sorton", promoTable.table.get(0).config.sortList).trigger("appendCache").trigger("applyWidgets");
     prevNext();
     return;
    });
   },
   Cancel: function() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
   }
  },
  width: '440px'
 });
```

If there is a better way, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

A function is a function, regardless of whether it's anonymous or named.  So if you have this:

```
$('something').click(function () {
    // do something
});

$.someOperation({
    someOption: function () {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Then you can simply do this:

```
var doSomething = function () {
    // do something
};

$('something').click(doSomething);

$.someOperation({
    someOption: doSomething
});
```

Functions are first-class citizens in JavaScript, so they can be passed around like any other variable.